# How to get <a>data only if start with '#' python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Hello im trying to get hashtags list from caption..
only will scraping data if only the data start with '#'

```
hashtags = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li > div > div > div._a9zr > div._a9zs > span > a")

for tag in hashtags:
    print(tag.text)
```

it still mixed with @ data

```
@flutter_coding_
#softwareengineer
#iosdeveloper
#webdeveloper
#flutterdeveloper
#frontenddeveloper
#appdeveloper
#programming
#softwareengineer
#coding
#code
#100daysofcode
#javascript
#reactjs
#developer
#developerlife
#programminghumor
#coderlife
#python
#php
#desksetup
#appdevelopment
#uidesign
#frontend
#backenddeveloper
#codinggirl
#flutter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `startswith()` method to sort and to get the data items those contain only `#`

```
for tag in hashtags:
    if tag.startswith('#'):
        print(tag.text)
```

Try:
At first,you have to invoke `.text` method then `startswith(`)` method with if condition

```
for tag in hashtags:
    tag=tag.text
    if tag.startswith('#'):
        print(tag)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cal filter the list with a comprehension:

```
hashtags = ["@flutter_coding_", "#softwareengineer", "#iosdeveloper"]
hashtags = [i for i in hashtags if i[0]=="#"]
print(hashtags )
```

**Output:**

```
['#softwareengineer', '#iosdeveloper']
```

Comment: `for tag in hashtags:
    hashtags = [i for i in hashtags if i[0]=="#"]
    print(hashtags)`

got an error `TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not subscriptable`